# Is there a way to construct a self-centering axle?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

Suppose I have a flat plate of arbitrary but connected shape.

If I try to connect an axle perpendicular to the plate it is very difficult to align it with the centre of mass, creating wobble when the axle and plate are rotated.

Is there a mechanical device that can be attached to the axle and plate that causes the axle to be self-centering to the centre of mass of the plate?

Comment: Are you looking for casters - such as fitted to trolleys of all types and designed into car steering?

Comment: Do you expect that to adjust while the axle is rotating fast? or some helping device for adjusting before to spin the axle? or you don't care?

Comment: @Adrian Maire: The plate would be in a horizontal position while rotating. The case of most interest would be a disk of say a meter in diameter, or a shallow dish containing fluid. Rotational speed would not be more than about 1 rev/s.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Adjustment could occur while the assembly is spinning, or it could be fixed while spinning at high rotational speed.

Comment: @SolarMike A mechanism containing casters could work, not sure how to go about designing a self-centering one because casters usually return to a chosen position.

Comment: Some shafts are designed as "self-centering" by the use of tapers ie they taper into the central point...